# How to create a MXBean with control methods?

Tags: kotlin, corda

We are planning to implement some behaviour control in our 
CordApp, for testing purposes. Is that possible to create a 
M(X)Bean, accessible via JMX, which is going to change some
internal flags in our CordApp ? If this is not a good design 
choice, please inform the best practice to follow.

Basically, we have a set of flags, like these:

```
abstract class BaseFlow() : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
    var flagBehaviourOne  : Boolean = true
    var flagBehaviourTwo  : Boolean = true
    var flagBehaviourThree: Boolean = true
    var flagBehaviourFour : Boolean = true
...
}
```

then, in some implementing class, we have something like this:

```
object SomeFlow {
    @InitiatingFlow
    class Initiator(private val destinatario: Party,
                    private val parameter: StateObject,
                    private val isAnonymous: Boolean = false,
                    private val pointer: Any) : BaseFlow() {
    ...
        @Suspendable
        override fun call(): SignedTransaction {

        if (flagBehaviourOne || flagBehaviorTwo) { 
            // enforce some specific behaviour
        }

    ...

    } // end of SomeFlow.Initiator

...  

} // end of SomeFlow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have (partially) solved my problem.

I have added a new `object` class, along with its jmx interface :

```
package vfalcao.example.jmx

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
import javax.management.MXBean
import javax.management.ObjectName

@MXBean
interface BehaviourControlMXBean {
    fun setBehaviourOne(newValue: String)
    fun isBehaviourOne() : String
    ...
    // other "behaviours" ommited for brevity
}

object BehaviourControl : BehaviourControlMXBean {
    // internal data
    ...
    init {
        val objectName = ObjectName("vfalcao.example.jmx:type=BehaviourControl,name=def")
        val platformMBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()
        platformMBeanServer.registerMBean(this, objectName)
    }
}
```

then, in my `BaseFlow` class:

```
abstract class BaseFlow() : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
   companion object {
      ...
      init {
          println("${BehaviourControl}")
      }
      ...
      fun test() {
          var behaviour1 = ((BehaviourControl.props["behaviour1"] as String).toBoolean())
          if (behaviour1) { 
             // do something controlled by behaviour1
          }
      }

   }
   ...
}
```